# How to draw a 3d rendered Image (perspective proj) back to another viewport with orthogonal proj. simultaniously using multiple Viewports and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, viewport, opengl-3

My problem is that i want to take a kind of snapshot of a 3d scene manipulate that snapshot and draw it back to another viewport of the scene,

I just read the image using the glReadPixel method.
Now I want to draw back that image to a specified viewport but with the usage of modern OpenGL.

I read about FrameBufferObject (fbo) and PixelBufferObject (pbo) and the solution to write back the FrameBufferObject contents into a gl2DTexture and pass it to the FragementShader as simple texture.

Is this way correct or can anyone provide a simple example of how to render the image back to the scene using modern OpenGL and not the deprecated `glDrawPixel` method?

Comment: That is the general process, though I do not know why you need an FBO in this example. FBOs are useful when you want to draw offscreen or into a texture, this is neither of those two things from your description. A PBO alone would be more than sufficient, and the term "CPU memory" is generally referred to as "client memory" in OpenGL; knowing this might help you better understand some of the documentation you will have to read to implement this.

Comment: Ok maybe the problem was not described enought. I have an application with different viewport. One viewport shows somekind of simulation and i just want to take a snapshot as 2d image of this 3d simulation and manipulate that and show the result wtihin another viewport,. All simultaniasly. Maybe my title is not quit correct.

Comment: Do you really want to do this on the CPU? This is a prime candidate for shaders, in which case an FBO would be the only tool (besides shaders) that you need.

Comment: Yeah your right. The performance issue i know. But at first i want to see if it works this way becaue the operation i want to perform on the image is currently just avaibale as c code. I know that i have to implement a special shader. Its an academical problem.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman. I just want to know at this time how to draw back the FBO to a specified viewport. I think in this case it is just an openGL (technical) problem.

Comment: How the heck is this question too broad? OP explained what he was doing, mentioned what he tried, and asked what to do. This is a very reasonable question, and @AndonM.Coleman and I were both able to help him without trouble.

Comment: @GraphicMuncher i appriciated your answer and i also don't know what's goin on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall process you want to do will look something like this

1. Create an FBO with a color and depth attachment. Bind it.
2. Render your scene
3. Copy the contents out of its color attachment to client memory to do the operations you want on it.*
4. Copy the image back into an OpenGL texture (may as well keep the same one).
5. Bind the default framebuffer (0)
6. Render a full screen quad using your image as a texture map. (Possibly using a different shader or switching shader functionality).

Possible questions you may have:

- **Do I have to render a full screen quad?** Yup. You can't bypass the vertex shader. So somewhere just go make four vertices with texture coordinates in a VBO, yada yada.
- **My vertex shader deals with projecting things, how do I deal with that quad?** You can create a subroutine that toggles how you deal with vertices in your vertex shader. One can be for regular 3D rendering (ie transforming from model space into world/view/screen space) and one can just be a pass through that sends along your vertices unmodified. You'll just want your vertices at the four corners of the square on (-1,-1) to (1,1). Send those along to your fragment shader and it'll do what you want. You can optionally just set all your matrices to identity if you don't feel like using subroutines.

*If you can find a way do your texture operations in a shader, I'd highly recommend it. GPUs are quite literally *built* for this.

Comment: No i have programmed something which is able to assign different projections to the viewports so this should be no problem

Comment: But one problem i have. What is the difference between Scissor and Viewport and what happens when you call ReadPixels when already multiple viewports are drawn within the framebuffer. That are my questions

Comment: You can use `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` to avoid drawing a fullscreen quad. But as strange as this might sound (since `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` was designed to do only one thing), drawing a fullscreen quad tends to be quicker than copying framebuffer data from a read buffer to a draw buffer using `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` :)

Comment: Ah ok i already read about this within "SuperBible" but it seemed to be no solution for my problem. But i will have a look again.

Comment: To your second possible question. You are completely right. This question i had too and i also thought about a different shader which just ignors the view projection. Thx. Seems to me that you are a pure expert. Looking forward to ask you some more questions.

Comment: @ChristianSchack: Scissor is used for defining the region of the screen where all fragment operations are allowed to occur. This is a fancy way of saying: do not shade/clear anything that appears outside of this region. The viewport on the other hand defines the portion of the window that your 3D scene is projected onto to produce a 2D image. The best way to show the difference between the two is to watch how setting `glScissor (...)` and `glEnable (GL_SCISSOR_TEST)` affects the result of a `glClear (...)` operation (after changing the clear color) while `glViewport (...)` has no affect.

Comment: Ahh yes i think i already saw this scissor affect during my experiments with that operation but i thought no this seems to be also not my solution. Thx. Your explanation is really clear! Did you already thought about writing a book or a sophisticated tutorial. Really honestly.

Comment: What should i do to get rid of this downvote. Additionally i think i have to improve my question. After that conversation this problem is not trivial at all (in my oppinion). Thank you for your help Mr. Coleman

Comment: Mention what you've tried to do, but couldn't accomplish. But honestly there are just some people who are serial downvoters :(

Comment: Yeah i just recognized that fact. It's a pitty. Seems that humanity is also representated within virtual (social) networks. But in possitive and negative way. Thank you Sir it helped me really much. I think we will see us concerning these kind of questions.

Comment: I just removed the accept button because  i expect some more ideas. I will give it back to you back anyway.

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher thank yoiu for your really sophisticated answer and your given plan. You are completely right with the GPU - CPU aspect. I also think that the operator i want to use is better located within the shader. But at the current state i just want to draw back the result back a viewport as previous mentioned.